# String Indices in swift

Tags: swift

Use the indices property to access all of the indices of individual characters in a string.
Reference Swift documentation.

```
let greeting = "Guten Tag!"

for index in greeting.indices {
    print("\(greeting[index]) ", terminator: "")
}
// Prints "G u t e n   T a g ! "
```

but when i tried

```
for index in greeting {
    print("\(index) ", terminator: "")
}
// Prints "G u t e n   T a g ! "
```

so what is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In the first method, i.e.**

```
    for index in greeting.indices
    {
        print("\(greeting[index]) ", terminator: "")
    }
```

`indices` property is used on `greeting` to get all the valid indices corresponding to the string `greeting`.

```
greeting.indices
```

> The indices that are valid for subscripting the collection, in
>   ascending order.

Then a `fast enumeration` is executed on all the returned valid indices to access each element of the greeting using subscript, i.e.

```
greeting[index]
```

**In the second method, i.e.**

```
    for index in greeting
    {
        print("\(index) ", terminator: "")
    }
```

in the above code, `fast enumeration` is executed on the string itself that loops on every element of the `greeting`. Since the element is returned directly, there is no need to use subscript.

This is all possible, since `String` is also a `Collection` and hence supports almost all the API's available for a `Collection`.

Comment: what is the real world benefit? and which one you will use?

Answer (score 0):

In the first code block, you are `fast enumerating` the `indices` of the `greeting` string. `Indices` is the indices that are valid for subscripting the collection, in ascending order. When you do fast enumerate the `indices`, each element is an `index`, actually a `String.Index`, and you may use such `String.Index` to access each element (a `Character`) of your string varaiable.

The second code block, you are fast `enumerating` the `element` (`Character`) itself of your string. It's pretty simple to see the differenct.

Press AltOption + Left Click to your variable `index` in your loops to see the magic.

Hope this helps!